# Is there anyway to upgrade AzureDevops 2019 on premise to Azure Devops 2022 on premise

Tags: azure-devops

My question is simple.

I was wondering about if is there any way to upgrade?

When I read this article, I thought I can upgrade 2019 to 2022.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/migrate/migration-overview?view=azure-devops-2022

But for now, I haven't find any way to do it yet.

Comment: The guide you linked is to migrate from Azure DevOps Server (on prem) to Azure DevOps Services (cloud) From the title of you question you don't want to migrate to the Azure DevOps Services, you want to to an on prem upgrade to the latest version of Azure DevOps Server. [2019 -> 2022 is supported](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/upgrade/get-started?view=azure-devops-2022)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. you can updates... the steps will be same as here: [Upgrade Azure DevOps Server to 2020](https://oshamrai.wordpress.com/2021/01/18/upgrade-azure-devops-server-to-2020/)